# What's the best way to implement data storage in Swift, how to deal with class change

Tags: swift, sqlite, core-data, plist, userdefaults

I am a new swift programmer here, and I am practicing it with my own project, when I was implementing data storage, I found that there are so many methods to do it, such as UserDefaults, Plist, CoreData ...
I chose Plist as my own data persistence method, instantly I found there is an issue, to store those custom classes, I need to make it following the Codable protocol.

For example, my custom class User has variables and functions

```
class User: Codable {
  
   var name: String
   var gender: Gender
   var avatar: Data
   var keys: Int
   var items: Array<Item>
   var vip: Bool
   
   var themeColorSetting: ThemeColor? = nil

   
   public init(name: String, gender: Gender, avatar: UIImage, keys: Int, items: Array<Item>, vip: Bool) {
       self.name = name
       self.gender = gender
       self.avatar = avatar.pngData() ?? Data()
       self.keys = keys
       self.items = items
       self.vip = vip
   }
   
   public func getAvatarImage() -> UIImage {
       return UIImage(data: avatar) ?? UIImage()
   }
   
   
}
```

This works fine when I store it to the Plist,
But when I tried to add a function

```
public func setAvatarImage(_ image: UIImage) {

        avatar = image.pngData() ?? #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Test").pngData()!
    }
```

to the class, I found that the original data can't be read because it doesn't have the new function in the coded file, and this even leads to crushing when I upload a new build to TestFlight,

So what's the best way to store the data that still works even when I add new variables or functions in the future, or how do you deal with the Refactor or Extension to a class.
Thank you so much

The crushing issue caused by updating User class:

I've got

```
Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x10355e3a8)
```

```
class AppManager {
  public static let shared = AppEngine()
public var currentUser: User = User(name: "User", gender: .undefined, avatar: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Test"), keys: 3, items: [Item](), vip: false)
  public let dataFilePath: URL? = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first?.appendingPathComponent("item.plist")

  init() {
    loadUser()
  }

 public func loadUser() {
        
        if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: dataFilePath!) {
           let decoder = JSONDecoder() //PropertyListDecoder()

           do {
                self.currentUser = try decoder.decode(User.self, from: data) 
           } catch {
               print(error)
           }
        }
        
        if self.currentUser.vip {
            print("Welcome back VIP!")
        }
    }

}
```

When I don't call loadUser(), it works fine as there is a stored default user in AppManager, this all happened when I just simply add a new function to the User Class, if I delete the App and reinstall it, It works fine with loadUser() called

Comment: Adding a new method shouldn't be an issue. What else did you change?

Comment: I found that every time when I change the class, the old version of stored data can't be read

Comment: Can you show a [mcve]?

Comment: I edited my question, I am pretty sure that the issue is caused by changing the User class, the old coded file doesn't have the new function, User should be loaded every time when users open the App

Comment: As @Sweeper points out, adding a method should not alter `Codable`'s ability to decode your `User` object.  Adding stored properties will affect it, however.  Your code doesn't show any property changes, but the difficulties you're encountering suggests that you probably did - perhaps in one of the property types (like `Item` or `Gender`).

Comment: Hi Chip, so what I want to know is, for example, I have finished the App and uploaded to App Store, what If I want to add a property, let's say age, in the future,  then I add the property and upload a new version to App Store, users have installed the new version, then they can't read the data because of the change, does this means I can't change the class if I use Plist once I start operating the App?

Comment: You make your new property optional or supply a default value if it isn't set.

Comment: @ChristianLiu, I actually address that in the answer I posted.

Comment: @ChristianLiu I just realized that I hadn't addressed what to do if you have an app that was already encoded using Swift's synthesized `Codable` implementation.  I did answer how to handle once you implement `Codable` yourself.   I just updated my answer to address that short-coming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although your code and description suggest that you only added methods, not properties, simply adding a method to `User` should not alter the ability of `PropertyListDecoder`, or `JSONDecoder` to decode it.  However, if you did add a stored property, *or* if you changed the other `Codable` properties, such as `Item` or `Gender`, you might very well be unable to decode it from data that was encoded from a previous version of those types.

One way to track it down, and also provide some backward compatibility for future changes you might make to `User`'s stored properties, would be to fully implement the `Codable` protocol in `User` rather than relying on the one Swift synthesizes for you.

`Codable` is basically just a combination of two other protocols, `Encodable` and `Decodable`.

`Encodable` requires a function, `encode(to: Encoder) throws`.  `Decodable` requires an initializer, `init(from: Decoder) throws`.

`Encoder`s will serialize your class to an "object" type, which is essentially a dictionary.  So you'll need a type to act as a key for that dictionary and it needs to conform to the `CodingKey` protocol.  It should have a specific value for each property you want to serialize.  Normally, it's implemented as an `enum`.

For your `User` class you could add:

```swift
enum CodingKeys: CodingKey
{
    case name
    case gender
    case avatar
    case keys
    case items
    case vip
    case themeColor
}
```

With the `CodingKey` taken care of, you can now implement the required methods in `User`:

```swift
public required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws
{
    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    
    self.name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
    self.gender = try container.decode(Gender.self, forKey: .gender)
    self.avatar = try container.decode(Data.self, forKey: .avatar)
    self.keys = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .keys)
    self.items = try container.decode([Item].self, forKey: .items)
    self.vip = try container.decode(Bool.self, forKey: .vip)
    self.themeColorSetting = try container.decode(ThemeColor?.self, forKey: .themeColor)
}

public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws
{
    var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    try container.encode(self.name, forKey: .name)
    try container.encode(self.gender, forKey: .gender)
    try container.encode(self.avatar, forKey: .avatar)
    try container.encode(self.keys, forKey: .keys)
    try container.encode(self.items, forKey: .items)
    try container.encode(self.vip, forKey: .vip)
    try container.encode(self.themeColorSetting, forKey: .themeColor)
}
```

Note that this does mean you'll have to maintain your `CodingKeys` and these methods when you add properties. However, it does a few things for you that you don't get from the automatically synthesized implementation.

For starters, if you find that you are failing to decode a previously encoded `User`, you can enable a breakpoint on `Swift.Error` in Xcode.  The debugger will stop on the specific property that's failing to decode.  You don't get that with Swift's synthesized `Codable` implementation.

Another thing explicitly implementing `Codable` yourself gives you is the ability to deal with the possibility of adding fields that might be missing in previously encoded instances.  For example, let's say you add an `isModerator: Bool` property, but you want to be able to decode existing `User` instances that didn't have that property.  No problem.

First you add the `isModerator` property itself to `User`:

```swift
var isModerator: Bool
```

Then you update your `CodingKeys`:

```swift
enum CodingKeys: CodingKey
{
    case name
    case gender
    case avatar
    case keys
    case items
    case vip
    case themeColor
    case isModerator // <- Added this
}
```

Then you update `encode(to: Encoder) throws`:

```swift
public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws
{
    var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    try container.encode(self.name, forKey: .name)
    try container.encode(self.gender, forKey: .gender)
    try container.encode(self.avatar, forKey: .avatar)
    try container.encode(self.keys, forKey: .keys)
    try container.encode(self.items, forKey: .items)
    try container.encode(self.vip, forKey: .vip)
    try container.encode(self.themeColorSetting, forKey: .themeColor)
    try container.encode(self.isModerator, forKey: .isModerator) // <- Added this
}
```

And then finally, in `init(from: Decoder) throws`:

```swift
public required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws
{
    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    
    self.name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
    self.gender = try container.decode(Gender.self, forKey: .gender)
    self.avatar = try container.decode(Data.self, forKey: .avatar)
    self.keys = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .keys)
    self.items = try container.decode([Item].self, forKey: .items)
    self.vip = try container.decode(Bool.self, forKey: .vip)
    self.themeColorSetting = try container.decode(ThemeColor?.self, forKey: .themeColor)

    // Add the following line, using nil coalescing to provide a default value 
    // for old serialized Users that didn't have this property.
    self.isModerator = try container.decodeIfPresent(Bool.self, forKey: .isModerator) ?? false
}
```

**Note**: If you're adding a property to a class that was encoded using the synthesized implementation and are now supplying your own version, the `enum` cases you give for `CodingKeys` have to match the previous property names exactly, although Swift does provide some conversion from JSON-style "snake case" to Swift-style "camel case".  You can also try making `String` extension conform to `CodingKey`, and use `String` literals for your coding key instead.  If you want to see what keys are being used, convert the `Data` from the encoder to a `String` and print it.  Unfortunately converting to a string will fail by default with `Data` produced by `PropertyListEncoder`, because its default output format is binary.  In that case, save it to a file, and open it in Plist Editor to see the keys being used.

Providing your own `Codable` implementation also means you don't have to encode every property.  For example, you might have some property on `User` that is transient - it only is meaningful during a session, and doesn't need to be stored.  Since you're already explicitly encoding your properties, and you don't want to encode that transient one, there is nothing to do in `encode(to: Encoder) throws`.   You can initialize it in all of your initializers, including `init(from: Decoder) throws` just as you would in any initializer... or initialize at the point of declaration and you don't even have to touch initializers.

Comment: I think I did change the properties in other related classes, but I just forgot, then I tested it by adding a method to the user class, and the coded data can be read after I added Thank you so much, it is useful for me, I still need to learn more about the data storage part, thanks for your effort